# How to select folders to sync in UbuntuOne?

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one

Can I selectivly select what folders I want to sync in Ubuntu One? If so how? Currently I created a symlink from Ubuntu One folder to the folder I want to share? That will not waste space right (duplicate data), but I suppose Ubuntu One is supposed to be better integrated with Dropbox and I should not need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the folder you want to sync in Nautilus.
2. Right-click with the mouse.
3. Select 'Ubuntu One / Synchronise This Folder

[image]

Comment: For me, only the last option is enabled, the rest are grayed out, any idea why is that?

Comment: I think if you are already synchronising any individual files or sub-folders in a folder, you can't later select the parent folder for sync. Try checking for this and disable sync for any, then select the whole folder.

Comment: I found its because I am trying to sync outside my home folder ... still don't understand why Ubuntu One restricts that ... even symlink won't work. Reverted to Dropbox

Comment: Just use both, each have good features. You don't have to choose one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

open nautilus, navigate to the parent folder of the folder you want to sync, click with the right button of your mouse in the folder you want to sync, choose ubuntuone > sync this folder.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 13.10. In Nautilus when I right click on the directory icon inside my home directory there is no option "Ubuntu one "