# Sharing subfolders with Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select folders to sync in UbuntuOne?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98110/how-to-select-folders-to-sync-in-ubuntuone)

Is it possible to share subfolders with Ubuntu One? Say, if your documents in one folder are put into author folders - can I just share "root" document folder and other account can download all subfolders? or do I need to share each subfolders separately?

Comment: check this [link](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+question/180623) hope its help you.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. If you share a folder with a person, that person gets the folder you shared and all subfolders.